# Tensorflow: What if my cond is not a scalar in tf.cond in while loop?

Tags: python, tensorflow

in `tf.cond` of tensorflow, `cond` has to be a scalar, but in my case `cond` need to be rank 1 with shape [batch_size]. Is there any method to solve this problem? Have tensorflow provided a solution to it?

```
import tensorflow as tf
seq_len = 10
while_length = 10
batch_size = 4

output_ta = tf.TensorArray(
        dtype=tf.int32,
        size=seq_len,
        tensor_array_name='example_1')

cond_tensor = tf.constant([3, 4, 5, 6])


def _step(time, arrays):
    time_tensor = tf.tile(tf.expand_dims(time, -1), multiples=[batch_size])
    arrays = arrays

    def _true_function():
        return tf.constant([1] * seq_len)

    def _false_function():
        return tf.constant([0] * seq_len)

    bool_cond = tf.less(time_tensor, cond_tensor)
    arrays_write = tf.cond(bool_cond, true_fn=_true_function, false_fn=_false_function)
    arrays = arrays.write(time, arrays_write)
    return time + 1, arrays


trace_time, outputs_tensor_arrays = tf.while_loop(
        cond=lambda time, *_: time < while_length,
        body=_step,
        loop_vars=[0, output_ta],
        parallel_iterations=32,
        swap_memory=True)

axes = [1, 0]
output = tf.transpose(outputs_tensor_arrays, axes)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(output)
```

Answer (score 1):

One potential solution I realized is `tf.where`:

```
import tensorflow as tf

seq_len = 10
batch_size = 4

output_ta = tf.TensorArray(
    dtype=tf.float32,
    size=seq_len,
    tensor_array_name='example_1')

cond_tensor = tf.constant([3, 4, 5, 6])

t1 = tf.ones(shape=[batch_size, seq_len])
t2 = tf.zeros(shape=[batch_size, seq_len])


def _step(time, arrays):
    time_tensor = tf.tile(tf.expand_dims(time, -1), multiples=[batch_size])
    # arrays = arrays

    bool_cond = tf.less(time_tensor, cond_tensor)
    output_array = tf.where(bool_cond, t1, t2)
    # arrays_write = tf.cond(bool_cond, true_fn=_true_function, false_fn=_false_function)
    arrays = arrays.write(time, output_array)
    return time + 1, arrays


trace_time, outputs_tensor_arrays = tf.while_loop(
    cond=lambda time, *_: time < seq_len,
    body=_step,
    loop_vars=[0, output_ta],
    parallel_iterations=32,
    swap_memory=True)

axes = [1, 0, 2]
output = outputs_tensor_arrays.stack()
output = tf.transpose(output, axes)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    r_output = sess.run(output)
```